# Closeable bottom bar with slide animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a bar for the bottom of my webpage that has a nice animation, similar to this one: http://css-tricks.com/pop-from-top-notification/ but stays on screen until it is closed. This is all the css I have so far:

```
.about {
background: black;
text-align: left;
position: fixed;
z-index: 100; 
bottom: 0; 
left: 0;
width: 100%;
color: #0f0;
font-size: 21px;
font-family: Timeburner;
padding: 10px;
}
```

I don't care if it takes jquery or somthing else, as long as it works.

Comment: Please paste jsfiddle :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rhq1s0vo/ - here you go!

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this css:

```
@-webkit-keyframes slideUp {
   0%   { -webkit-transform: translateY(50px); }
   100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
}
@-moz-keyframes slideUp {
    0%   { -moz-transform: translateY(50px); }
    100% { -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
}
 #note {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px);
    -webkit-animation: slideUp 2.5s 1.0s 1 ease forwards;
    -moz-transform:    translateY(-50px);
    -moz-animation:    slideUp 2.5s 1.0s 1 ease forwards;
}
```

here is the [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6hcu57t0/)

here is your example with the Css animation: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6cdu4g4/) (you will need to add the JS for the close button)

here is and example with slide down on close: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shyz134w/) it uses Jquery but can also be done using pure JS:

```
 close = document.getElementById("close");
 close.addEventListener('click', function() {
     $("#note").slideUp();
 }, false);
```

Comment: Not what i'm looking for, I even linked to that in my question. I want a bar for the bottom of my webpage that has a nice animation, similar to this one: http://css-tricks.com/pop-from-top-notification/ but stays on screen until it is closed. Your example closes after half a second and has none of the css in my question, could you pease update you fiddle?

Comment: Can you make it slide back on close? @Hassene Benammou

Comment: Sorry, I cant get the close to work. could you make it work with the .about class? (Sorry, I have no skill whatsoever) @Hassene Benammou

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60929/discussion-between-8bitcodecat-and-hassene-benammou).